# Meaning of :: and use of Function<>?

Tags: java, lambda

I have two question when learning lambda expression in java.

1. When we use `::` in java.
   I see in the book using `Employee::getSalary` but lack of explanation.
   Do we use `::` when we want to implement some function of the class (like `getSalary()` method in class `Employee`)?
2. `Function<Employee,double> salary = Employee::getSalary`
   Do Function here like we create method `public static double salary(Employee e)`?

Thanks.

Comment: This link helps you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html